# Invalid Datetime format conversion issue

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have written this:

```
    Dim sysFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
    Dim formatDate = sysFormat + " " + "h:mm:ss tt"
    Dim dtttm As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, formatDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And the `value` value ! is string **"08/11/2017**"  and `sysFormat` value is **M/d/yyyy**  But I get an Invalid Date Format  exception.

Why is it invalid ? What is invalid in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sysFormat is just the day, but you are appending a 12 hour time format. You must also include the time with AM/PM in `value`

Instead of **"08/11/2017"**, use **"08/11/2017 1:02:03 PM"**. It will work.